# How to pass an Array from Parent Component to Child Component in react by using Statefull Component?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project, I am trying to pass an array from Parent component to Child component in react with stateful component.

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child/Child'

const students = ['Mark','Williams']


class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child studentsArray = {students} ></Child>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Child.css';

class Child extends Component {
render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <ul>
                    {this.props.studentsArray.map(student => `<li> ${student} </li>`)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Child
```

Comment: and what's the problem you're having?

Comment: @albert My Output is coming like this -> <li> Mark </li><li> Williams </li>

Comment: ah, just remove the backticks and that should work

Comment: Yeah you don't need to use string literals here.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child studentsArray = {[1,2,3,4,5]} ></Child>
      </>
    );
  }
}
class Child extends Component {
render() {
  return (
      <ul>
       {this.props.studentsArray.map(student =>
        <li> {student} </li>)}
      </ul>
        )
    }
}
```